# Web Api to upload excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core-webapi

I work on asp.net core 2.2 web API using C# language

I need to rewrite function below with best syntax and with best practice

web API below get Excel file from upload and return Excel file

it working without any issue but I need to rewrite it with best syntax and practice

some points I need to changes :

concatenate path is best thing using

are streaming using correctly

are memory copying file is correct

```
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    [Route("Upload")]
    public IActionResult Upload()
    {
        try
        {
            var DisplayFileName = Request.Form.Files[0];
            string fileName = DisplayFileName.FileName.Replace(".xlsx", "-") + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xlsx";
            string Month = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
            string DirectoryCreate = myValue1 + "\\" + Month + "\\" + fileName;
            string exportDirectory = myValue2 + "\\" + Month;
            string exportPath = myValue2 + "\\" + Month + "\\" + fileName;
            string FinalPath = exportPath;
           
            if (!Directory.Exists(DirectoryCreate))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(DirectoryCreate);
       
            }
            if (!Directory.Exists(exportDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(exportDirectory);
      
            }
            CExcel ex = new CExcel();
            if (DisplayFileName.Length > 0)
            {
                var filedata = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(Request.Form.Files[0].ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                var dbPath = Path.Combine(DirectoryCreate, fileName);
            
                using (var stream = new FileStream(dbPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    Request.Form.Files[0].CopyTo(stream);
                    stream.Flush();
                    stream.Close();
                }
                GC.Collect();
                string error = "";
                int rowCount = 0;
                string inputTemplatePath = "";
              
                var InputfilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(GetFilesDownload, "DeliveryGeneration_Input.xlsx");
                bool areIdentical = ex.CompareExcel(dbPath, InputfilePath, out rowCount, out error);
                if (areIdentical == true)
                {
                    List<InputExcel> inputexcellist = new List<InputExcel>();
                    inputexcellist = ex.Import(dbPath);
                    List<string> mods = new List<string>();
                    mods = inputexcellist.Select(x => x.ModuleName).Distinct().ToList();
                    var OutputfilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(GetFilesDownload, "DeliveryGeneration_Output.xlsx");
                    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(exportDirectory, fileName)))
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Ok so the error message IS right.");
                    }
                    System.IO.File.Copy(OutputfilePath, Path.Combine(exportDirectory, fileName), true);
    
                    SqlConnection con;
                    foreach (var m in mods)
                    {
                        List<InputExcel> inputmodulelist = new List<InputExcel>();
                        inputmodulelist = inputexcellist.Where(x => x.ModuleName == m).ToList();
                        var dtimport = DatatableConversion.ToDataTable(inputmodulelist);
                        DataTable dtexport = new DataTable();
                        dtexport = _deliveryService.LoadExcelToDataTable(_connectionString, dtimport);
                        ex.Export(dtexport, m, exportPath);
    
                    }
                }
                var memory2 = new MemoryStream();
                using (var stream = new FileStream(exportPath, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(memory2);
                }
                memory2.Position = 0;
    
                return File(memory2, "text/plain", Path.GetFileName(exportPath));
    
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex}");
        }
    }
```

**Update original post**

function above get excel file as input with some data

then I search on database for matched data input

then get matched data on database on output file

then on last download it with output data

I using name space

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using OfficeOpenXml;
```

Comment: wait a minute, how does it work ? I can see you're storing the file in a directory, and in the end you're loading an excel from the database. Is the file stored twice ? as it seems you're getting a full `DataTable` from the database, not some metadata that could reference the actual file. please give us more details.

Comment: 1-get Excel file I uploaded from front end
2- create folder path as input
3-get data from database and export data to excel sheet with multi tab
4-then download out file multi tab it

Comment: I get input file then fill it with data from database then output Excel file with data come from database

Comment: What Excel library are you using ?

Comment: i updated original post

Answer (score 2):

### **Naming Convention**

current code is not using `camelCase` naming convention on local `variables`, and also is not given a good naming to some variables like `DisplayFileName`, `Month`, `DirectoryCreate` ..etc.it should be cameled-case.

Some variables have wrong naming like `DisplayFileName` it should be `file` because it's used for `Request.Form.Files[0]` and not to `Request.Form.Files[0].FileName`. `dbPath` is not best name for explaining a file that is related to the stored one. It could be changed to `fileToComparePath` since it's going to be compared with the input file and the `exportPath` can be `fileExportPath`.

it's important to always differs between `Directory` and `File` paths by either suffix the `file` or `dir` to the name, otherwise, it won't be a clear enough to other developers.

When dealing with `paths` you should always use the built-in methods for like `System.IO.File` and `System.IO.Directory`. This would ensure the compatibility with the current system requirements.

Short names are fast to type, easy to miss, and hard to follow. So, try to avoid short names like `CExcel ex = new CExcel();` it would be better to name it `excel` rather than `ex`, and also `var m in mods` in the `foreach` loop.

Always give your variables a good explainable naming.

### **using**

with `using` clause, there is no need to `Flush` or `Close` or `Dispose`, as it would automatically do that at the end of the block.

So this :

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(dbPath, FileMode.Create))
{
    Request.Form.Files[0].CopyTo(stream);
    stream.Flush();
    stream.Close();
}
```

should be like this :

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(dbPath, FileMode.Create))
{
   // you should use Write(stream) instead, or reset the stream position.
    Request.Form.Files[0].CopyTo(stream); 
}
```

**Unused variables**
`FinalPath`, `filedata`, `inputTemplatePath`, `con` why they're still there ? you should remove unused variables.

**Other Notes**

- When working with files and directories, it would be wise to use the built-in methods `Directory`, `File` and `Path` to avoid any unexcepted exceptions that have been already covered by them.
- with `if` conditions, don't put the exception or the error at the `else`, keep it at the top as it would be clearer than to be at the end of the code.
- when doing `ToList()` it'll return a new `List`.
- with `Stream` always use `Write` instead of `CopyTo` as `Write` is specific use and optimized for `Stream`, while `CopyTo` is built for all compatible collections types.

**Code Comments**

here is some comments on the code (code has been shorten for brevity).

```
if (DisplayFileName.Length > 0) // should be inverted.
{
//  var filedata = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(Request.Form.Files[0].ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"'); //unused 
 
    var dbPath = Path.Combine(DirectoryCreate, fileName); // this would return ../path/month/fileName-SomeGUID.xlsx/fileName-SomeGUID.xlsx

    using (var stream = new FileStream(dbPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        Request.Form.Files[0].CopyTo(stream);
        // the Flush() and Close are handled by the `using` blocks
//      stream.Flush();
//      stream.Close();
    }
    
//  GC.Collect(); // unnecessary
    
    string error = ""; // use null;
    
    int rowCount = 0;
    
//  string inputTemplatePath = ""; //unused
  
    var InputfilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(GetFilesDownload, "DeliveryGeneration_Input.xlsx");
    
    bool areIdentical = ex.CompareExcel(dbPath, InputfilePath, out rowCount, out error); // rowCount and error have never been checked. what happens if they have values ? 


    if (areIdentical == true)
    {
//      List<InputExcel> inputexcellist = new List<InputExcel>();// unnecessary
        
        List<InputExcel> inputexcellist = ex.Import(dbPath);
       
//      List<string> mods = new List<string>(); // unnecessary
        
        // it could be used in the foreach directlry  
        List<string> mods = inputexcellist.Select(x => x.ModuleName).Distinct().ToList();
        
        var OutputfilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(GetFilesDownload, "DeliveryGeneration_Output.xlsx");
        
         // This is unnecessary as the `File.Copy` ovewrite flag is true.
         // Although Directory.Exists should be File.Exists 
        // if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(exportDirectory, fileName)))
        // {
             // throw new Exception("Ok so the error message IS right.");
        // }

        // Path.Combine(exportDirectory, fileName) has the same value of exportPath 
        System.IO.File.Copy(OutputfilePath, Path.Combine(exportDirectory, fileName), true);


//      SqlConnection con;  // unused

        foreach (var m in mods) // m should be moduleName or name
        {
//          List<InputExcel> inputmodulelist = new List<InputExcel>(); // unnecessary

            List<InputExcel> inputmodulelist = inputexcellist.Where(x => x.ModuleName == m).ToList();

            DataTable dtimport = DatatableConversion.ToDataTable(inputmodulelist); 
            
//          DataTable dtexport = new DataTable(); // unnecessary

            DataTable dtexport = _deliveryService.LoadExcelToDataTable(_connectionString, dtimport);

            ex.Export(dtexport, m, exportPath);

        }
    }
    
    
    var memory2 = new MemoryStream();
    
    using (var stream = new FileStream(exportPath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        stream.CopyTo(memory2);
    }
    
    memory2.Position = 0;
    
    
    // Path.GetFileName(exportPath) is equal to fileName
    // "text/plain" ? why ? you should use the appropriate mime type for Excel 
    // for .xls  = application/vnd.ms-excel
    // for .xlsx = application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
    // or just use the ClosedXML Web API Extension
    return File(memory2, "text/plain", Path.GetFileName(exportPath)); 

}
else
{
    // invert the if, and move this at the top of blocks 
    return BadRequest();
}
```

**Suggested Revision**

```
if(Request.Form.Files.Length == 0)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException(" No Files");   
}

var file = Request.Form.Files[0];

var fileName = $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName)}-{Guid.NewGuid()}.xlsx";

Func<string, string> generateFilePath = (path) => 
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName) 
    ? Path.Combine(Directory.CreateDirectory(path).FullName, DateTime.Today.Month.ToString() , fileName) 
    : null;

var fileToComparePath = generateFilePath(myValue1);

var fileToExportPath = generateFilePath(myValue2);

if(fileToComparePath == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fileToComparePath));
}

if(fileToExportPath == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fileToExportPath));
}

using(var fileStream = File.Create(dbPath))
{
    fileStream.Write(file);
}

if(!ex.CompareExcel(fileToComparePath, Path.Combine(GetFilesDownload, "DeliveryGeneration_Input.xlsx"), out int rowCount, out string error))
{
    return BadRequest();
}

File.Copy(Path.Combine(GetFilesDownload, "DeliveryGeneration_Output.xlsx"), fileToExportPath, true);

CExcel excel = new CExcel();

foreach (var moduleName in excel.Import(dbPath).Select(x => x.ModuleName).Distinct())
{
    var inputModuleList = inputexcellist.Where(x => x.ModuleName == moduleName).ToList();

    var tableImport = DatatableConversion.ToDataTable(inputModuleList);
    
    var tableExport = _deliveryService.LoadExcelToDataTable(_connectionString, tableImport);

    excel.Export(tableExport, moduleName, fileToExportPath);
}

MemoryStream excelFileStream = new MemoryStream();

using(var fileStream = File.Open(fileToExportPath, FileMode.Open))
{
    fileStream.Write(excelFileStream);
}

return File(excelFileStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);
```

Comment: thank you very much for your advices but there are more things i need to ask 1-string exportDirectory = myValue2 + "\\" + Month; so my question are there are another way to concate path without using "\\"

Comment: also another thing how to avoid error The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process when create new file on my code

Comment: @ahmedbarbary use `Path.Combine` to concatenate paths as of my example above. For file processing, you should consider using `SafeFileHandle`  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safefilehandle?view=net-5.0

Comment: can you please help me how to use safefilehandle according to code above please only that what i need how to use safe file handle on code above. can you please help me

Comment: also how to use async task on web api above